# Accessing dictionary of lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my Python code :

```
import random
import itertools
per=itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3])
dict={}
for i in per:
    dict[i]=0

P=[2,1,3]

dict[P]=dict[P]+1
print(dict)
```

It gives an error saying

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in line  dict[P]=dict[P]+1
```

How do I correct this

I am expecting to increment the value of the key `[2,1,3]` by 1.

Comment: what you are expecting ?

Comment: I am expecting to increment the value associated with the key " [2,1,3] " by 1

Comment: You cant use a mutable object as a key to a dict. Use a tuple instead of a list.

Comment: lists cannot be assigned as dict key, try tuple instead.

Comment: Converting P to tuple worked ! Thanks Paul and Vikas.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may want to look at `defaultdict` or `Counter`, which might make your code a little more succinct. Also you should generally avoid using the names for built in functions as variable names. You use `dict` as a variable name. After this you cant use the built in function `dict`, as it's hidden. A good alternative name might be `d` or `counter`.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, you must provide `P` as a tuple. Later you can loop through the keys and check the keys and the increment as needed.

```
import random
import itertools
per=itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3])
dict={}
for i in per:
    dict[i]=0
P=(2,1,3)
for key in dict.keys():
    if key == P:
        dict[key] += 1

print(dict)
```

The above code handles the problem.

You can also do a `dict[P] += 1` provided that `P` is a tuple and a `key`of the form `P` exists in the dictionary. If the key don't exist it will throw an error. So to be safe I recommend the code I posted.